# node.js: Confusing usage of 'this' in the global scope

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been toying with node.js lately and I ran into a weird behavior about the usage of `this` in the global scope of a module.

`this` is bound to module.exports in the global scope:

```
console.log(this === exports); // -> true
```

But `this` is bound to global in a method scope:

```
(function() { console.log(this === global); })(); // -> true
```

This also lead to this confusing behavior:

```
this.Foo = "Weird";
console.log(Foo); // -> throws undefined

(function() { this.Bar = "Weird"; })();
console.log(Bar); // -> "Weird"
```

I guess that the solution is to never use `this` in the global scope and explicitly use `extends` or `global` instead, but is there a logic behind all this or is it a bug or limitation in node.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In working on a simple CommonJS modules implementation, I had to think about what to do with `this` in the global scope of the module; it's not addressed by the spec.

I also set it up as the `exports` object at first, because I thought that would be useful, but later [found some code](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-js-sdk/blob/master/src/third-party/json2.js#L160) I needed to "modulize" that was using `this` to get a handle to the global object, so I changed `this` back to the global object to provide as close of an environment to "normal" as possible for module code.

We can only guess at why node is set up the way it is (or ask the author), but my guess is it was done simply because it seemed like a useful idea, similar to the way you can give the `module` object an `exports` property in node and have it reflected in the module's actual `exports` (this behavior also isn't part of the spec, but doesn't go against it either).

As for the part of your question about `this` referencing `global` in functions, as the other answers explain, that's just the way `this` works; it's not a node-specific behavior, it's a weird javascript behavior.

Answer (score 7):

The "logic" behind that is, that the value of `this` always depends on **how a function is invoked**.

In your case, you have a self-executing anonymous function, there, `this` always references the global object (non strict mode) or `undefined` (ES5 strict).

If you want to access the "outer" `this` value, you could either store a reference before executing that function, like

```
var outerScope = this;

(function() { outerScope.Bar = "Weird"; })();
console.log(Foo); // -> throws undefined
```

or re- `.bind()` the functions scope yourself, like

```
(function() { this.Bar = "Weird"; }).bind(this)();
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be less confusing if `this` in the global scope was bound to `global` instead of `extends` then? I would expect `this` to mean the same in the global scope and a static function scope.

Comment: @SelflessCoder: I honestly don't know why this is bound to the `exports` object. But in general its a good idea NOT to clobber the global object with data. So, just keep in mind that any function-context can have a different `this` value, depending on how it is called.

Comment: As jAndy says, this is basically how `this` works in javascript. I haven't read any discussion on it, but I guess that having `this === exports` in global scope is supposed to be analog to `this === window` in the global scope in a browser. IMO, having `this === global` in global scope makes less sense, since that would mean that `this.foo === foo`.

Comment: @Linus G Thiel: In the browser that last expression is `true`, so I think `this === global` would be more logical in fact.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the exact intention of Node.js team, but I would be surprised if it was not. Consider this example ran in the dev console of a browser (e.g. chrome):

```
var x = function(){console.log(this)}
a = {}
a.x = x
a.xx = function(){x()}

a.x()
>> Object
a.xx()
>> DOMWindow
x()
>> DOMWindow
```

As you can see executing a method without specifying its context sets the context to be the global one. In this case the DOMWindow object.

When you are inside a module your context is the module, but executing a method in it without specifying a context with .call or .apply or obj. will use the global context, `global`, instead of the local one, `module.exports`.