# Why does `eval` work on non-strings?

Tags: javascript, standards, eval

I was playing around with `eval` and noticed that it can evaluate non-strings in Chrome, Firefox and Opera:

```
eval(Array) === Array; // true
eval(this) === this;   // true
eval(4 * 3 / 2) === 6; // true
```

Is this a standard behavior? Is it documented anywhere? I can't find any mention of `eval` taking anything other than a string argument.

If this isn't a standard behavior, can someone identify host environments where this *doesn't* work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without a string, the code is already evaluated at a lower level, namely before it is passed to eval (e.g. your last statement is just doing `eval(6)`). That's the case for any function; it's how JavaScript code is evaluated. `eval` is not magical in that sense because it's "just" a function that "just" accepts an argument.

What `eval` should return when am expressions is passed that is not a string is described in [the specification](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1.2.1):

> 1. If Type(`x`) is not String, return `x`.

Comment: Yeah, I just found that. I had no idea `eval` worked like that.

Comment: +1 You beat me to it. Also wanted to mention that if x is not a string, it just returns x

Comment: I don't suppose there's any reason to actually *use* `eval` like this, is there?

Comment: @GGG: Indeed there's not, since `eval` is plainly a noop this way. I guess there isn't a reason to use `eval` with a string either due to its security issues.

Comment: @pimvdb apparently there are useful [corner cases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642491/getting-a-reference-to-the-global-object-in-an-unknown-environment-in-strict-mod/9647292#9647292) for regular `eval`...