# Using .apply or .call on setTimeout - how to get this context in cross platform manner

Tags: javascript

In browsers, `setTimeout` lives in `window` or `self`, which are equal. In web workers, only `self` is present. On Node.js, `global` represents the global context and `setTimeout` exists within it. And there are more than just these two javascript platforms.

I need to call a `setTimeout` function but I have an arbitrary number of arguments to pass to it - 3rd and following arguments are passed to the callback. In browser of web worker, this works:

```
setTimeout.apply(self, [alert, 666, "Hello"])
```

Node.js console accepts this:

```
setTimeout.apply(global, [console.log, 500, "Hello."])
```

So what's the general answer? How to use apply on function with unknown or variable `this` scope without breaking that scope?

**Edit to clarify:** because it appears one solution might be to get access to global object using some procedure that detects it, I want to clarify that I was hoping to fetch `this` scope **from the function I'm gonna call**. Something like inversion of `.bind` - get the `this` scope and apply it, so that it works even **on non global** functions. The idea:

```
setTimeout.apply(setTimeout.getThisObject(), [alert, 666, "Hello"])
```

Comment: What about `this`? Means `global` in node and `window` in browsers...

Comment: Are you asking how to get a reference to the global object in a cross-platform way? See [Getting a reference to the global object in an unknown environment in strict mode](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9642491/1529630)

Comment: `this` does not mean global when the function that executes the code belongs to an object. Which is quite often in bigger applicatons that mimic OOP.

Comment: @TomášZato If possible, can clarify what actual Question is ? What is expected result  ?

Comment: I am sorry if I wasn't clear for the first time and I also admit @Oriol proposed possible solution already, but when asking the question, I hoped for **getting the `this` scope** bound to a function. The opposite of bind, which *sets* the `this` scope.

Comment: @TomášZato At edited Question : _"want to clarify that I was hoping to fetch this scope from the function I'm gonna call."_ , "fetch `this` _from_" or _set_ `this` scope _at_ ? Why not _set_ `this` scope ? Can create stacksnippets , jsfiddle to demonstrate actual application of described procedure ? , Detail expected results that would be different from using `.bind()` ?

Comment: If the sample pseudo code isn't clear enough to picture whether I'm setting or getting the scope, I don't know what can be clearer. Especially then, since I named the method **`getThisObject`**, not `setThisObject`.

Comment: @TomášZato Your edit seems to assume the value of `this` becomes fixed when you create a function. That is false in general, `this` may depend on how you call the function.

Comment: Not even that since `bind` exists.

Comment: @TomášZato Then, are you asking, given a reference to a function which you know was created with `bind`, how to get that bound `this`? I don't think you can.

Comment: @Oriol Actually, I was about to start a new question about that once I have this one answered. But it seems javascript specification regarding this in functions till needs some work.

Answer (score 0):

`this` corresponds to the global object when called outside of any function scope. Thus, simply bind `this` to a variable outside any function scope:

```
var globalObject = this;
// ...rest of your code...
function foo () {
  setTimeout.apply(globalObject, ...)
}
```

Or, in IIFE style:

```
(function (global) {
  // ...rest of your code...
  setTimeout.apply(global, ...)
}(this))
```

You might even want to have the IIFE's `this` bound to the global `this`, although that may prove a bit confusing:

```
(function (global) {
  // ...rest of your code...
  setTimeout.apply(this, ...)
  var foo = function () {
    setTimeout.apply(global, ...)
  };
}.bind(this)(this));
```