# function(exports) returns an error "Cannot set property 'weekDay' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, adobe-brackets

so I'm going through a 'Modules' Chapter of Eloquent JS book and I've encountered a problem with the function(exports) part.

```
(function (exports) {
var names = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
           "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

exports.name = function (number) {
    return names[number];
};
exports.number = function (name) {
    return names.indexOf(name);
};
})(this.weekDay = {});

console.log(weekDay.name(1));
```

returns

```
Cannot set property "weekDay" of undefined
```

However in the online editor on the book's website exactly the same code runs without problems and return "Monday".

I'm wondering if it's a problem with Adobe Brackets.

Comment: Omit the `this.` and everything will be fine. Looks like you're trying to assign to a variable, not create a property on some object that you don't know (and that apparently doesn't exist here).

Comment: @Bergi Yes, that works! thank you. I, however, wonder why it works with _this_ on the website [here](http://eloquentjavascript.net/10_modules.html), it's under **Objects as interfaces** part.

Comment: As the next paragraph says, "*The previous pattern is commonly used by JavaScript modules intended for the browser.*", in which case "*Outside of a function, `this` refers to the global scope object.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a module pattern that doesn't rely on being executed in a global script scope where `this` would be the global object. I recommend

```
var weekDay = (function (exports) {
    var names = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
               "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    return {
        name: function (number) {
            return names[number];
        },
        number: function (name) {
            return names.indexOf(name);
        }
    };
}());
```

So yes, this was caused by your environment, but the code was fragile in the first place. If you want to continue to use that `exports` thing, you can also do

```
var weekDay;
(function (exports) {
    …
})(weekDay = {});
```

or alternatively check [How to get the global object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3277182/1048572) and [Getting a reference to the global object in an unknown environment in strict mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9642491/1048572).