# Variable within a variable javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

I need to call a variable from within a variable.

I have a variable called vmX_cores. I need to loop through the vms I have and call that variable dynamically.

```
var vms = ["vm1", "vm2", "vm3"];
var totalVms = vms.length;

var vm1_cores = 2;
var vm2_cores = 4;
var vm3_cores = 8;

function ifScript() {
   if (totalVms == 0) {
      return 'done';
   } else {
      var curVM = vms[totalVms - 1];
      var variableToUse = curVM + '_cores';
      totalVms--;
      return 'notDone';
   }
}
```

When I call variableToUse this returns "vmX_cores" but I need it to return the number not a string.

Comment: Use an object instead of three variables

Comment: y not use `vm_cores = {1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 8}`;

Comment: the vm_cores variables are set elsewhere in the code that I cant change, I just need to call it. And I was just giving an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A global variable is accessible as a property of the global object, which is `window` for a browser and `global` for node. See [Getting a reference to the global object in an unknown environment in strict mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642491/getting-a-reference-to-the-global-object-in-an-unknown-environment-in-strict-mod)

Since you have the name of the variable/property, you can use bracket access.

```
// This code works in ES3, ES5 and strict mode to get the global object
var globalObj = (function(){ return this || (1,eval)('this') })();
var variableToUse = curVM + '_cores';
var actualValue = globalObj[variableToUse];
```

Comment: I thought this was going to work but I got: WrappedException of "window" is not defined

Comment: Did you even look at the link I posted in my answer? You can use `global` in node, but the link tells you a better way

Comment: That worked! Thank you! I did as `var global = (eval)(variableToUse);` then called global and I got the right number

Comment: @huan0602 That is not what that post was saying, you are using `eval` to evaluate the variable name, which is usually frowned upon. In this case, there's no problem because all the variables being `evaled` are under your control. I've updated my answer with the correct answer that works under node and the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window[vmX_cores]` to get the value of that variable string.

eg : 
`var x = window["vm1_cores"]`

In your case :

`var x = window[variableToUse]`

Comment: Note: this will not work if the OP's code is inside a function or a node module.

Comment: Would technically work, but would not be the correct way of doing it, so I'll give you a ±0.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Please share the correct way or point out what the problem is

Comment: It was posted in the comments for OP - use an object, not separate variables.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen but under the same comments, the OP explained that they didn't have control over that, the variables were declared somewhere else

Comment: Then they should get whoever can change that code to change it because it's terrible.

Comment: @mattivirkkunen yeah but sometimes you just can't do it, no need to rant, the OP explained it