# How to create an alias for 'window'?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a javascript app that uses a lot of global variables:

```
window.x = 0;
window.y = 0;
```

I'd like to be able to use an alias for the window object:

```
w = window;
w.x = 0;
w.y = 0;
```

However, when I set w to window, it seems to recursively add itself to the DOM:

```
w = window;
// In the DOM Explorer:
> w   page.html
>   w   page.html
>     w   page.html...
```

This seems like it would ruin the memory, but the app is running fine. Is there a better way to create global variables or a window alias?

Comment: Why not just declare them outside of everything at the top of your script then you don't need to add `window.`? Or are you reusing names and namespacing?

Comment: `window.window.window.window.document.title` is legit and doesn't waste RAM... in the same way, since `w==window`, `w.w.w.w == window.w.window.w`. in short: no problem...

Comment: _"it seems to recursively add itself to the DOM"_ - not really the DOM, window isn't part of it strictly speaking; but anyway, window is the top-most object in JS run in the browser, and _every_ global variable you declare becomes a property of the window object - so does your `w` variable here, what value it has doesn't play any part in it. Circular references, mostly between JS variables and actual HTML element objects, used to be a problem in browsers, IE in combination with event handling had famous memory holes; what you are doing here however should not cause any browser any trouble.

Comment: That being said, if you are writing an app, you might want to look into ways to better encapsulate your code and its data from the "outside world" anayway; an IIFE is a starting point for something small-scale.

Comment: The reason it appears to recursively add it to the DOM is because your having the object reference itself. This isn't a problem and will not consume any more memory than adding a property to any other object. In JavaScript objects are referenced by memory address.

Comment: it would be nice if devtools differently styled "sub-objects" that == their parent

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you are declaring a variable without a var, you are effectively assigning it to window object.

So,

```
w = window;
```

becomes

```
window.w = window
```

and that's why the recursive behavior.

You can use an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) to achieve what you want.

```
(function(w) {
   w.x = 0;
   w.y = 0;
})(window)
```

Comment: what does does the IIFE do for us here?

Comment: Its a standard way to alias global objects like window, jQuery without adding more of our own, like w here. More about this [here](http://www.nicoespeon.com/en/2013/05/properly-isolate-variables-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

Your global variable doesn't waste memory, but you should avoid global variables.

```
(function() {
  var w = window; // Create local alias
  window.window; // window
  w.w; // undefined (probably)
})();
```

Of course, this assumes `window` points to the global object. If you want to get a reference to the global object even if `window` is shadowed, see [Getting a reference to the global object in an unknown environment in strict mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9642491/1529630).

Answer (score 0):

In all browsers excepts IE, **window.window** is just a hooky way to reference.. well.. window. So **window === window.window**, true.

And **window.window.window** is also the same as **window.window**.

**Info**: http://javascript.info/task/window-windowwindow