# ES6 module : global function?

Tags: ecmascript-6, twig

Is it possible to create global function with ES6 ? I would like use some function on my twig.

The problem is that my function is in an ES6 module. In twig, it is not possible to import the function.

Do you have an idea to counter this problem?

Comment: Same way as you would have in ES5, nothing's changed, assign it to the [global object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642491/getting-a-reference-to-the-global-object-in-an-unknown-environment-in-strict-mod). Or: https://github.com/ljharb/System.global

Comment: `var global = (1,eval)('this');` is the global function ? I'm not sure I understood very well

Comment: `var global = (1,eval)('this'); global.yourFunction = () => alert("Hello, World");`. `global` is the global context. `yourFunction` is the global function.

Comment: Haaa okey, I understand :) It work nice, thank you !